# DIsable microphone loopback

Tags: sound, audio

My headphones and microphone work fine, but **I keep hearing myself**.
Disabling the microphone mutes the noise, but I need it.

Is there an easy way to solve it? It's usually a toggle in the microphone config, but I can't see anything here. :(

Headset:
Logitech G430 Gaming Headset (USB)

OS:
Juno
Linux 4.15.0-64-generic
GTK 3.22.30

NOTE:
In `alsamixer` there's no `Loopback` option for the audio card of my headset, and the other audio cards have it `Disabled`.

EDIT: output of `lspci | grep Audio` :

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05) 
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Update your question with `lspci | grep Audio`. What's the model of the faulty card?. If you open `alsamixer` and press F5, does it show now a loopback device that you can disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in `alsamixer` for the sound card of my headset a dedicated volume column to *Mic*, in the `F3: Playback` view (and not `F4: Capture`!), lowering it to 0 solved my problem.

[image]